# My contact form for email is not working

Tags: php, html, html-email

My contact form is not working, nothing happens.

It redirect to `contact.php` page but click on button nothing happen even not show validation errors. What is the problem?

```
<form method="post" id="contact-form" action="contact.php">
    <h2>Send us your inquiry</h2>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <input name="mail" id="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <input name="tel-number" id="tel-number" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_contact" value="Send Message">
    <div id="msg" class="message"></div>
</form>

<?php 

/* ==========================  Define variables ========================== */

#Your e-mail address
define("__TO__", "123@mydomain.com");

#Message subject
define("__SUBJECT__", "examples.com = From:");

#Success message
define('__SUCCESS_MESSAGE__', "Your message has been sent. Thank you!");

#Error message 
define('__ERROR_MESSAGE__', "Error, your message hasn't been sent");

#Messege when one or more fields are empty
define('__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__', "Please fill out  all fields");

/* ========================  End Define variables ======================== */

//Send mail function
function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
    if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
    }
}

//Check e-mail validation
function check_email($email){
    if(!@eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//Get post data
if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['mail']) and isset($_POST['comment'])){
    $name    = $_POST['name'];
    $mail    = $_POST['mail'];
    $website  = $_POST['website'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    if($name == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your name."));
        exit();
    } else if($mail == '' or check_email($mail) == false){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter valid e-mail."));
        exit();
    } else if($comment == ''){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your message."));
        exit();
    } else {
        //Send Mail
        $to = __TO__;
        $subject = __SUBJECT__ . ' ' . $name;
        $message = '
            <html>
            <head>
              <title>Mail from '. $name .'</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <table style="width: 500px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;" border="1">
                <tr style="height: 32px;">
                  <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Name:</th>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $name .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 32px;">
                  <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">E-mail:</th>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $mail .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 32px;">
                  <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Website:</th>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $website .'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 32px;">
                  <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Comment:</th>
                  <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $comment .'</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </body>
            </html>
        ';

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";

        send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of worked for me. The I had was that it showed an error the first time it showed. You don't sanitize $_POST. You don't need action either since it's on the same page.

Here is a version which a modified a little and works for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php 

/* ==========================  Define variables ========================== */

#Your e-mail address
define("__TO__", "123@mydomain.com");

#Message subject
define("__SUBJECT__", "examples.com = From:");

#Success message
define('__SUCCESS_MESSAGE__', "Your message has been sent. Thank you!");

#Error message 
define('__ERROR_MESSAGE__', "Error, your message hasn't been sent");

#Messege when one or more fields are empty
define('__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__', "Please fill out  all fields");

/* ========================  End Define variables ======================== */

//Send mail function
function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
    if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
    }
}

//Check e-mail validation
function check_email($email){
    if(!@eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
if (!(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['mail']) && isset($_POST['comment'])))
{
    ?>
    <form method="post" id="contact-form">
    <h2>Send us your inquiry</h2>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <input name="mail" id="mail" type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input name="tel-number" id="tel-number" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_contact" value="Send Message">
        <div id="msg" class="message"></div>
    </form>        
    <?php
}
else
{
    $data = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $name    = $data['name'];
    $mail    = $data['mail'];
    $website  = $data['website'];
    $comment = $data['comment'];

    if($name == '') {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your name."));
        exit();
    } else if($mail == '' or check_email($mail) == false){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter valid e-mail."));
        exit();
    } else if($comment == ''){
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your message."));
        exit();
    } else {
        //Send Mail
        $to = __TO__;
        $subject = __SUBJECT__ . ' ' . $name;
        $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Mail from '. $name .'</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <table style="width: 500px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;" border="1">
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Name:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $name .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">E-mail:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $mail .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Website:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $website .'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 32px;">
              <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Comment:</th>
              <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. $comment .'</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";

        send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
}  
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: bt my form code is in html page...how can I use this ?

Comment: The page I sent you is html code with some embedded php. You need to make sure that you have php correctly installed on your system.

Comment: u cant get what I said......my form page is contactus.html and coding page is contact.php.....so I can't use php code in html page...

Comment: I just tried with a separate contact.html form. It worked too.